# How can you convert UInt64.max to a String in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert `UInt64.max` to a `String`.

A line such as:

```
var str: String = UInt64.max
```

Results in an error in XCode that:

```
'UInt64' is not convertible to 'String'
```

As another example, a line such as the following:

```
let strFromUInt: String = NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: UInt64.max)
```

Results in an error in XCode that:

```
'NSNumber' is not convertible to 'String'
```

Sorry if I'm missing anything here, I'm quite new to iOS development still. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
var str = String(UInt64.max)
```

Basically that's the first thing you should try; in Swift, coercion works by initializing the desired type based on a value of another type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
var str = "\(UInt64.max)"
```